# How to get process ID of ClickOnce application from code

Tags: c#, clickonce, handle

I have a C# application (A.exe) which starts a clickOnce application 
(located on a server, path is: http://www.someplace.com/MyClickOnceUI/MyClickOnceUI.application).

I would like to get an handle for this ClickOnce application (please note that I cannot modify this clickonce app in any way). Below is the code I am using to launch this clickonce app:

```
  Process proc = new Process();
  proc.StartInfo.FileName = "http://www.someplace.com/MyClickOnceUI/MyClickOnceUI.application";
  //this starts the ClickOnce application
  proc.Start();
  //When I try to get the process ID, System.InvalidOperationException is thrown, stating "No process is associated with this object"
  int id = proc.Id;
```

Please let me know how can I get the handle of this clickonce application in my c# code.

**UPDATE**:
Sequence of applications that start at proc.Start() are:

iexplore.exe **->** dfsvc.exe(clickonce) **->** MyClickOnceUI.exe.

iexplore.exe is killed as soon as dfsvc.exe starts.

I want to get handle of dfsvc.exe or MyClickOnceUI.exe. Is there a way?

Thanks,

RDV

Comment: Does the application actually start when you call it from your C# code? Is it an installed application? It could be that the process that is started by your application is iexplore.exe and that spawns a subprocess that runs the ClickOnce app. The iexplore.exe process then quickly terminates before you call `proc.Id`.

Comment: Yes, my application starts from the code- you are correct, sequence of applications that start are: iexplore.exe->dfsvc.exe(clickonce)->MyClickOnceUI.exe. I need help to get handle of MyClickOnceUI.exe. Thanks